# How to retrieve the function called in an onload?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me to retrieve and change the value of an onload function?

i.e

i want to get the value of the onload on this tag:

```
 <body onLoad="test();">
```

is there a way for me to do this?

since i need to change the function being called on certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get it from `window.onload`.

```
var func = window.onload;
```

---

Given your example, you'll get a function that looks something like this:

```
var func = function(event) {
    test();
};
```

---

So then you can call your function whenever you need, though you won't have an `event` object to pass it.

```
func();
```

---

To change it, just do it sometime before the `onload` event happens:

```
<body onload="test();">

    <script>
    var func = window.onload;

    alert(func); // alerts the function

    if (condition_is_met) {
        window.onload = function() { 
            /* my new func */ 
        };
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

This will overwrite the original function with a new one. As long as you do it before the event occurs, your new function will be invoked.

Comment: i tried this

$(function test2(){
var x = window.onload;
alert(x);
});

i cant seem to get the value of the window.onload

Comment: @loopers: works for me: http://jsbin.com/ipekux/1/edit Click the `Run with JS` button on the right. What browser are you using?

Comment: i added it on the head so thats why it was returning nothing. thanks for this, this will get me trough i just now need to append another function on the onload